# Android CoordinatorLayout new google maps collapse effect

Tags: android, google-maps, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hi guys i'am trying to achieve the new google maps effects when collapsing the toolbar.
Anyone with the idea how it's done?
The image seems to collapse under the toolbar!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image_adega"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/list_wines_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_wines"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**To reproduce the effect go to:**
Maps - click some marker - and scroll the content

Some images of what i'm talking about:

### [image: Maps scrolling - 1]

### [image: Maps scrolling - 2]

[image: Maps scrolling - 3]

Comment: Sorry guys for the incomplete question but my laptop died and i was getting home